# Export to Excel - no data besides column headers

Tags: export

When we try to use the OOB feature of exporting to Excel from a default view in a list, or a view created in the UI, it works as expected.

But when we create a new view, using list view web parts, of dataform web parts, then whenever we export to Excel and open the .iqy file, the spreadsheet has no data. It shows the columns of the view, alright, but otherwise it's blank.

Has anybody here ever had this problem? How can this be solved?

BTW this is happening for us both in 2010 and 2013 environments.

**EDIT:** we just found that the problem was in the view parameters. If a view had filter parameters, it'll try to use those in the spreadsheet as well. However Excel won't be able to access any HTML/ASP.NET controls (which it won't embed in the spreadsheet), and it also won't be able to read from the querystring because there is none to read from. I'm still searching for a way to solve this, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We eventually found that the problem was in the view parameters. If a view had filter parameters, it'll try to use those in the spreadsheet as well. However Excel won't be able to access any HTML/ASP.NET controls (which it won't embed in the spreadsheet), and it also won't be able to read from the querystring because there is none to read from.

Comment: For reference: I had this problem with a calendar view, and no filters were listed in the view settings in the browser. PowerShell shows however that there is an implicit filter with all calendar views. The workaround was to use the "All Events" view instead of the Calendar view.